# A full list of all the new/popular databases and their uses?

Tags: database, openedge

Recently I have found that there are many new databases popping up all around my radar, and I would like to make a list of what they do and perhaps what their advantages/disadvantages are. I'll seed the list with some names and perhaps someone with more knowledge can chip in with some information about each and how they stack up. I hope this will fast become a comprehensive list of all the available database so that developers can leverage the right one for the job at hand!

### Relational Databases:

#### Established:

- [DB2](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/db2/)
- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)
- [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
- [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx)
- [Sybase](http://www.sybase.com/products)
- OpenEdge SQL

#### New:

- [RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com/learn-more/)

### Key-value stores:

- [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/index.html)
- [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)
- [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/)

### Document oriented Stores:

- [couchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)
- [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home)
- List item

### Graph DataBases:

- Neo4j
- AWS Neptune
- Sesame
- AllegroGraph
- different RDF/triplestores

Comment: Can't forget Oracle, or SQLite.

Comment: Such a list here would replicate a lot of other similar lists on the net, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Comment: @Martin: Indeed.... this seems a bit daft

Comment: you forgot SQL Server in your established list

Comment: I think you need two more categories: Bigtable-like systems (HBase, Hypertable ...) and Graph Databases (see my answer below regarding graphdb).

Comment: A big list sorted by popularity can be found here: http://db-engines.com/en/ranking

Answer (score 4):

The [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) database engine

- [self-contained](http://sqlite.org/selfcontained.html)
- [serverless](http://sqlite.org/serverless.html)
- [zero-configuration](http://sqlite.org/zeroconf.html)
- [transactional](http://sqlite.org/transactional.html)
- cross platform *Unix (Linux and Mac OS X), OS/2, and Windows (Win32 and WinCE) are supported out of the box. Easy to port to other systems.*
- [faster than heck](http://sqlite.org/speed.html)

With library for most popular languages

- [.Net](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)
- [perl](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=dbd+sqlite+&mode=module)
- Feel free to edit this and add more links

Comment: Don't forget "cross platform" & "faster than heck"

Comment: This is a wiki, you can edit this answer yourself if you want to add anything else.

Answer (score 1):

To file under both 'established' and 'key-value store': [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html).

Has transactions and replication. Usually linked as a lib (no standalone server, although you may write one). Values and keys are just binary strings, you can provide a custom sorting function for them (where applicable).

Does not prevent from shooting yourself in the foot. Switch off locking/transaction support, access the db from two threads at once, end up with a corrupt file.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler did an interesting [blog post](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DatabaseThaw.html) last year about non-relational databases starting to gain traction. He mentions:

- Drizzle (a "bare bones" relational database)
- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) (a document-oriented database)
- [GemStone](http://www.gemstone.com/products/smalltalk/) (an object-oriented database)

There is also Google's [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) which is described as "a sparse, distributed multi-dimensional sorted map".

I have been working with GemStone for a number of years now and the productivity gains is amazing - having the database store your objects directly removes the need to constantly marshall back and forth between tables and objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are **graph databases** like:

- [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/)
- [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/)
- [AllegroGraph](http://agraph.franz.com)
- different [RDF/triplestores](http://esw.w3.org/topic/LargeTripleStores)

A graph database stores data as nodes and relationships/edges.This is a good fit for semi-structured data, interconnected information and domains with deep relationships/traversal, for example social networks and knowledge representation. The data model is highly flexible and ["whiteboard friendly"](http://groups.google.com/group/nosql-discussion/msg/31f8f71a88142c68?pli=1). The underlying data model of the [semantic web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web), [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework), is also a (labeled, directed multi-)graph.

Other stackoverflow threads with information on graph databases:

- [The Next-gen Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282783/the-next-gen-databases/687790#687790)
- [Non-Relational Database Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189911/non-relational-database-design/1192822#1192822) (listing some +/-)
- [Have anyone used Graph based
  databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000162/have-anyone-used-graph-based-databases-http-neo4j-org)

Answer (score 0):

What about CassandraDB, Project Voldemort, TokyoCabinet?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt I'd use it in a mission-critical system, but [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) has always been very interesting to me.