# SQL Server: how to select First, Second and Third degree contacts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, contacts, contact-list

I'm working on a social web-site project and I need to list "First, Second and Third Degree Contacts" of my contacts. I'm using SQL Server AND C#

Assume a `contact` table like this:

[image]

For first degree contact:

- If `gulsah` is me then my first degree contacts are `burak,sennur`

Query I use to select this:

```
SELECT contact_2 FROM Contacts_Table WHERE contact_1 like 'gulsah'
```

For second degree contact:

If `gulsah` is me again then my second degree contacts are:  `mali`

What makes it difficult is to select contacts of my contacts who are not my first degree contact.

I can select mutual contacts but I guess it is not the right approach.

For example, to select mutual contacts of me (`gulsah`) and `burak`:

```
SELECT contact_1 FROM (SELECT * FROM Contact_Test 
  WHERE contact_2 like 'burak') a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT contact_1 FROM Contact_Test 
     WHERE (contact_2 = 'gulsah')) b 
ON a.contact_1 = b.contact_1
```

This query works but as I said, it's not the right approach for this job.

For third degree contact:

If `gulsah` is me again then my third degree contacts are_  `mehmet,ahmet`

I need to select contacts of my contacts' contacts who are not my first and second degree contact :)

[Here is a post from Linkedin which explains contact level.](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/administration/customer-service/ADM_CSV/581967-23863639)

Thanks for responses.

Comment: Have you looked at the possibility of using [hierarchy functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)  or recursive CTEs (plenty of examples on SO) to accomplish that? Not an answer, just an idea at this point.

Comment: Actually, I'm using hierarchy for an infinite sub category system using left and right fields but honestly, I couldn't understand how I can use this method for this question. I guess I need to store some data on contacts table like /1/2/5/ or am I wrong?

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but I see two rows: {gulsah,burak} and {burak,gulsah}. Don't they represent the same relationship?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558290/efficient-way-to-implement-linkedin-like-how-you-are-connected-to-feature

Comment: These two rows are there to check Approval for future development. For example; burak can be in gulsah's list but at the same time, gulsah might not want to be listed in burak's list. I just realized this is a silly approach. Anyway, you can ignore duplicate rows.

Comment: thanks @magma, I'll examine it.

Comment: @Burak, @Magma's link is very good. The answer to your question is yes, you do need to store a hierarchyid on each record, which will allow you to look at the specific paths within the tree thus formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

1. Add my contact to a special collected contact list.
2. For every contact in the collected list as `Contact_1` of the contact table, add its corresponding `Contact_2` unless that contact is already in the collected list.
3. Repeat step #2 the number of times that is the target degree number minus one.
4. Repeat the query in step #2 once more, but this time simply return the result set (do not add the rows to the collected list).

The script:

```
DECLARE @MyContact varchar(50), @DegreeNumber int;
SET @MyContact = 'gulsah';
SET @DegreeNumber = 3;

DECLARE @CollectedContacts TABLE (Contact varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @CollectedContacts (Contact) VALUES (@MyContact);

WHILE @DegreeNumber > 1 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @CollectedContacts (Contact)
  SELECT ct.Contact_2
  FROM Contacts_Table ct
    INNER JOIN @CollectedContacts cc ON ct.Contact_1 = cc.Contact
    LEFT JOIN @CollectedContacts cc2 ON ct.Contact_2 = cc2.Contact
  WHERE cc2.Contact IS NULL;

  SET @DegreeNumber = @DegreeNumber - 1;
END;

SELECT ct.Contact_2
FROM Contacts_Table ct
  INNER JOIN @CollectedContacts cc ON ct.Contact_1 = cc.Contact
  LEFT JOIN @CollectedContacts cc2 ON ct.Contact_2 = cc2.Contact
WHERE cc2.Contact IS NULL;
```

As you can see, both the degree number and 'my' contact are parametrisable. I'm using the `varchar` type for contacts, but that of course can easily be replaced with `int`, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

> What makes it difficult is to select contacts of my contacts who are not my first degree contact.

You could use the `EXCEPT` operator.

First-degree contacts:

```
SELECT contact_2 FROM contact WHERE contact_1 = 'gulsah'
```

Second-degree contacts who are not first-degree contacts:

```
SELECT
  contactB.contact_2
FROM 
  contact AS contactB
  INNER JOIN contact AS contactA ON contactA.contact_2=contactB.contact_1
WHERE contactA.contact_1 = 'gulsah'
EXCEPT
SELECT contact_2 FROM contact WHERE contact_1 = 'gulsah'
```

`EXCEPT` tells SQL server to return all the results from the first `SELECT` that do NOT appear in the second `SELECT`.

For third-degree contacts (who are not first- or second-degree contacts):

```
SELECT
  contactC.contact_2
FROM 
  contact AS contactC
  INNER JOIN contact AS contactB ON contactB.contact_2=contactC.contact_1
  INNER JOIN contact AS contactA ON contactA.contact_2=contactB.contact_1
WHERE contactA.contact_1 = 'gulsah'
EXCEPT
(
SELECT contact_2 FROM contact WHERE contact_1 = 'gulsah'
UNION
SELECT
  contactB.contact_2
FROM 
  contact AS contactB
  INNER JOIN contact AS contactA ON contactA.contact_2=contactB.contact_1
WHERE contactA.contact_1 = 'gulsah'
)
```

I don't hold high hopes for performance, but of course you will need to check this yourself.

---

As a side note:

```
I can select mutual contacts but I guess it is not the right approach.
```

Use `INTERSECT` for this.

Comment: I'll try this, I hope the low performance won't be an issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps: 
http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/

Comment: @Snoopy, this article is really good and magma also shared this link. I examined it carefully and I think this is one of the perfect solutions for my situation (except social graph databases). But in this article, the examples are written for PostgreSQL so I wasn't able to run it in MSSQL. For example this query wont work on sql;

"WITH RECURSIVE transitive_closure(a, b, distance, path_string) A..."

Comment: @Burak: SQL Server 2005 supports recursive common table expressions as well. I just doesn't use the ANSI standard syntax where the RECURSIVE keyword is required. If you leave out the `RECURSIVE` keyword, it should work with SQL Server as well.

Comment: @Burak: the problem with the model is, that it contains endless cycles (e.g. gulsah -> burak -> sennur -> gulsah) which cannot easily be detected using a recursive common table expression...

Comment: then what do you recommend? Which method should I follow? This article (graph link) is really a good example of how Linkedin works and that's the exact thing I need. I need to find relations between 2 random person. Instead of using recursive common table expression, what should I do? graph dbs? ([neo4j](http://neo4j.org/))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: what do you think about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192945/sql-server-2005-recursive-query-with-loops-in-data-is-it-possible  (see the comment from Jose Chama)

Comment: @Snoopy: yes, remembering the full path to an item seems to be the only way to detect an infinite loop (at least with SQL Server). But this might not be feasible for large results.