# How to rewrite this query (PostgreSQL) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Few days ago I have asked a question about 1,2 and 3. degree connections. [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768904/sql-server-how-to-select-first-second-and-third-degree-contacts) and @Snoopy gave an article link which can fix all my problems. [Article Link](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/09/07/graphs-in-the-database-sql-meets-social-networks/)

I have carefully examined this article but I was unable to use With Recursive query with SQL Server.

PostgreSQL Query:

```
SELECT a AS you,
   b AS mightknow,
   shared_connection,
   CASE
     WHEN (n1.feat1 = n2.feat1 AND n1.feat1 = n3.feat1) THEN 'feat1 in common'
     WHEN (n1.feat2 = n2.feat2 AND n1.feat2 = n3.feat2) THEN 'feat2 in common'
     ELSE 'nothing in common'
   END AS reason
 FROM (
 WITH RECURSIVE transitive_closure(a, b, distance, path_string) AS
 ( SELECT a, b, 1 AS distance,
     a || '.' || b || '.' AS path_string,
     b AS direct_connection
FROM edges2
 WHERE a = 1 -- set the starting node

 UNION ALL

 SELECT tc.a, e.b, tc.distance + 1,
     tc.path_string || e.b || '.' AS path_string,
     tc.direct_connection
FROM edges2 AS e
JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON e.a = tc.b
 WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' || e.b || '.%'
 AND tc.distance < 2
 )
 SELECT a,
   b,
   direct_connection AS shared_connection
 FROM transitive_closure
 WHERE distance = 2
 ) AS youmightknow
 LEFT JOIN nodes AS n1 ON youmightknow.a = n1.id
 LEFT JOIN nodes AS n2 ON youmightknow.b = n2.id
 LEFT JOIN nodes AS n3 ON youmightknow.shared_connection = n3.id
 WHERE (n1.feat1 = n2.feat1 AND n1.feat1 = n3.feat1)
 OR (n1.feat2 = n2.feat2 AND n1.feat2 = n3.feat2);
```

or just

```
WITH RECURSIVE transitive_closure(a, b, distance, path_string) AS
( SELECT a, b, 1 AS distance,
     a || '.' || b || '.' AS path_string
FROM edges
WHERE a = 1 -- source

UNION ALL

SELECT tc.a, e.b, tc.distance + 1,
     tc.path_string || e.b || '.' AS path_string
FROM edges AS e
JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON e.a = tc.b
WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' || e.b || '.%'
)
SELECT * FROM transitive_closure
WHERE b=6 -- destination
ORDER BY a, b, distance;
```

As I said, I don't know how to write a recursive query with SQL Server using CTEs. Made a search and examined [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml) but still no luck. I couldn't run the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone interested, here is the answer;

I managed to convert the query in question to SQL by;

1. converting integer values to varchar(MAX). If you don't specify the length of varchar as MAX, you'll get "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column..."
2. I replaced || to +
3. I added ; to the beginning of query
4. Finally as @a_horse_with_no_name proposed I removed RECURSIVE from query.

***Result;***

```
;WITH transitive_closure(a, b, distance, path_string) AS
( SELECT a, b, 1 AS distance,
 CAST(a as varchar(MAX)) + '.' + CAST(b as varchar(MAX)) + '.' AS path_string
FROM edges
WHERE a = 1 -- source

UNION ALL

SELECT tc.a, e.b, tc.distance + 1, 
CAST(tc.path_string as varchar(MAX)) + CAST(e.b as varchar(MAX)) + '.' AS path_string
FROM edges AS e
JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON e.a = tc.b
WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(e.b as varchar(MAX)) + '.%'
)
SELECT * FROM transitive_closure
WHERE b=6 -- destination
ORDER BY a, b, distance;
```

Answer (score 2):

The recursive CTE should be the same on SQL Server (at least on a recent version, this was introduced with SQL Server 2005 if I'm not mistaken), just leave out the `recursive` keyword.

Note that SQL Server does not comply with the SQL standard and therefor you need to replace the `||` concatenation with `+`

Comment: I removed recursive and it works but I couldn't run this query.

`SELECT 
  edges.a  as a,
  edges.b  as b,
  1 AS distance,
  a + '.' + b + '.' as path 
FROM
  edges`

Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.' to data type int

I tried to use CAST but no success.

Comment: @Burak: apparently `a` and `b` are not varchar columns. You will need to cast them in order to be able to concatenate them. Try `cast(edges.a as varchar) + '.' + cast(edges.b as varchar)`

Comment: I managed to run this query : `SELECT 
  edges.a  as a,
  edges.b  as b,
  1 AS distance,
  CAST(a AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' + CAST(b AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' as path 
FROM
  edges`