# Is it still recommended to use junction tables if you would only ever join from one side of the relationship?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a database design in which I have aprox. 5 entities that can be filtered. Currently these tables all have their own filter table, e.g. the product table has a productfilter table and the customer has a customerfilter table.

I have done some research since performance (as in speed to query the db) is the most important quality attribute, I am wondering whether having a single filter table and connecting the entities that rely on it with junction tables is a better option?

Important side note the filters would only ever be joined from the Customer or Product entities when using the junction tables.

Edit:

**1: Without junction tables**

[image: database design 1]
**2: With junction tables**

[image: database design 2]

Comment: Could you post your intended database design?  Do the filters span different entities (i.e. can you run a filter against products and customers in a single query)?

Comment: I added an image of the intended database design. As far as running a filter against multiple entities in a single query, I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: Tables--base variables & query results--represent relation(ship)s/associations. [Queries do not have "sides" (or "links") & do not need to be "connected" to query--just mentioned.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329503/3404097) FKs though sometimes wrongly called relationships are constraints on what states can arise to allow integrity & optimization. Constraints need not hold or be declared or be known to query. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text.