# For a many to many relationship is it better to use relational database or nosql?

Tags: many-to-many, relational-database, nosql

For a many to many relationship is it better to use relational database or nosql?

Let's assume you have a bunch of users. And each user can have friends that are from the same users table. So it's essentially a many to many relationship to itself. Many to many relationship in relational database will create a third table. Now I was wondering assuming this user table is huge like millions of people in there, this third table would be thus be gigantic assuming let's say each person has more than 10 friends each. Wouldn't it be more efficient for friends(and just overall more intuitive) to be stored as a json list in a nosql as shown below?

```
{"user1": "friendslist":["user2","user3","user4"]}
{"user2": "friendslist":["user1","user3","user4"]}
{"user3": "friendslist":["user1","user2","user4"]}
{"user4": "friendslist":["user1","user2","user3"]}
```

so this is also a data structures question so it would be btree vs hash table if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What have you learned from (re)searching [relational vs not/NoSQL](https://www.google.ca/search?q=google+stackoverflow.com+relational+vs+nosql), especially from the relational point of view?

Answer (score 0):

It does seem more intuitive to the untrained. That's why the network data model is still so prevalent even though the relational model has been around for decades.

"Better" depends on how you want to use it, and "more efficient" depends on the database engine, indexes and various other factors. I prefer the relational model since I can formulate any reasonable question that can be logically derived from the data and get a correct answer. For example, if I wanted to find friends of friends, I could join a relational many-to-many table with itself. I could find cycles and cliques of any particular size. I could easily declare a unique constraint on pairs of friends.

It's possible to do these things without a relational database but I doubt it would be as easy or concise.

The particular data structure used by the database engine has nothing to do with the relational concept, though it is relevant to efficiency. For more info on which data structure would be used, you'll need to look at particular database management systems and their storage engines.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a relational implementation be "gigantic"? Why would your structure be "more efficient"? You are making a lot of unfounded assumptions that it would be good for you to think about. (Learn some relational basics. And the relational take on relational vs NoSQL.)

Re "intuitive", the obvious relational organization for when U friended F is a table Friended holding rows where... "U friended F". `Friended(U,F)` for short. If you want Us where U friended x, that's the rows where `Friended(U,x)`, ie the rows in `PROJECT U RESTRICT F x Friended`, ie the rows in `PROJECT U (Friended WHERE F=x)`, depending on whether you want to think in logic, relations or a mix. What's *your* query for that? Using a relational interface in terms of predicates and tables does not require or preclude any particular implementations. The entire NoSQL movement is a sad consequence of lack of understanding by users and vendors of the relational model as interface to data, not as storage structure. A DBMS for a NoSQL use case needs only to be a relational DBMS better supporting arbitrary types in querying and implementation.

From my answer to [Adjustable, versioned graph database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28799902/3404097):

> There is an obvious 1:1 correspondence between your states at a given time and a relational database with a given schema. So there is an obvious 1:1 correspondence between your set of states over time and a changing-schema database, ie a variable whose value is a database plus metadata, manipulated by both DDL and DML update commands. So there is no evidence that you shouldn't just use a relational DBMS.
>
> Relational DBMSs allow generic querying with automated implementation at a certain computational complexity with certain opportunities for optimization. Any application can have specialized queries that make a specialized data structure and operators a better choice. But you must design your application and know about such special aspects to justify this. As it is, with the obvious correspondences between your states and relational states, this has not been justified.

> Just because you can draw a picture of your application state as of some time using a graph does not mean that you need a graph database. What matters is what specialized queries/expressions you will be evaluating. You should understand what these are in terms of your problem domain, which is probably most easily expressible per some specialized data structure and operators and relationally. Then you can compare the expressive and computational demands to a specialized data structure, a relational representation, and the models of particular graph databases.

Of course there are specialized applications where we use optimized special operators and storage. But that merits justification, and from a relational perspective should supported by an extendible relational DBMS.