# Reasonable Export of Relational to Non-Relational Data

Tags: rdbms, relational, non-relational-database, nosql

We have different products that rely on relational databases for various reasons--the transactional nature of the operations, atomicity, consistency, etc. This is not going to change.

What are justifications to export the data to another solution--NoSQL, Datawarehousing, Analytics, etc.?

Comment: What does your research show? What even are definitions of "relational" and "NoSQL"? Alas this is too broad, a faq, and unresearched. Eg google your title.

Answer (score 0):

"Data" is just a vague generality without a data structure. "Relational" means the data structure is relations/tables with generic queries. (*Not* automatically interleaved execution of semantically atomic concurrent transactions, which just happens to become *feasible* given relational set-at-a-time operators.) *Need* for specialized data structures or queries suggests *augmenting* a relational system interface or implementation. "[NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278302/3404097)" is a catch-all for all sorts of such systems with special-case abstractions and/or implementations. But they don't need to be non-relational in interface. They just need to be not what current "relational" DBMSs provide. Given that they exist, one can reasonably export to (or import from) them when *needed*.

Unfortunately the relational model is not generally understood (including by "relational" DBMSs), so instead these systems [reject what they could simply extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212536/3404097).