# How to convert an existing relational database to a key-value store?

Tags: database, redis, rdbms, key-value-store, leveldb

I am trying to map a existing relational database to a key value store. Couple of example tables are represented below.

[image: Example tables in the RDBMS Databse]

For an instance the above "Employee Details" table can be represented as follows in Redis (or any similiar key-value store)

```
set emp_details.first_name.01 "John"
set emp_details.last_name.01 "Newman"
set emp_details.address.01 "New York"

set emp_details.first_name.02 "Michael"
set emp_details.last_name.02 "Clarke"
set emp_details.address.02 "Melbourne"

set emp_details.first_name.03 "Steve"
set emp_details.last_name.03 "Smith"
set emp_details.address.03 "Los Angeles"
```

The "Payments" table also can be represented as above. But this method does not build the one-to-many relationship between the "Employee Details" table and the "Payments" table. Therefore, is there any better way of implementing a key-value store from an existing RDBMS. You can refer to these two tables and suggest a better key schema to store values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include text as text, not images/links. We can cut & paste or search those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nosql databases are basically aggregate stores. Relationships and its associated values are stored in a 'value'  part of key - val design.

Avoiding joins  helps in better performance.

Excellent llink on nosql modeling -
 https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

[Relational *tables* represent *business/application relationships/associations*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) FKs (foreign keys) get *called* relationships but aren't. (They're just truths about every business/application situation & corresponding database state.) A FK constraint declaration just tells the RDBMS to enforce that subrows appear elsewhere as a superkey (unique key). (Although the DBMS can use it to optimize.) Constraints are not needed to query relationally.

FKs are relational. In a non-relational DBMS if you want to make *certain queries simpler or faster*, eg when they are the equivalents of certain relational joins involving certain FKs, *at the expense of complicating updates & other queries*, then you do things like record data redundantly, or in a nested/hierarchical way, or using pointers/indirection.

This difference in relational vs non-relational schemas & querying is fundamental to the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278302/3404097) in data models & to the benefits of the relational model. Using relational tables as data structure allows straightforward application-neutral querying with with certain implementation computational complexity & optimization opportunities. Any intro to a particular [NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44327398/3404097) DBMS will explain how to model & query. (Typically assuming an initial *relational* design.)